# Send pdf in base 64 to print

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to send base 64 for printing, I need to open the chrome print window, but my code just opens the pdf file in a new window. there is no problem with a regular html page, and when there is a pdf element on the page, it is not displayed

```
var objbuilder = '';
    objbuilder += ('<object width="100%" height="100%"      data="data:application/pdf;base64,');
    objbuilder += (base64PDF);
    objbuilder += ('" type="application/pdf" class="internal">');
    objbuilder += ('<embed src="data:application/pdf;base64,');
    objbuilder += (base64PDF);
    objbuilder += ('" type="application/pdf" />');
    objbuilder += ('</object>');
var win = window.open("","_blank","titlebar=yes");
        win.document.title = "My Title";
        win.document.write('<html><body>');
        win.document.write(objbuilder);
        win.document.write('</body></html>');
        win.print()
```

Comment: Can you refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27248259/create-html-page-and-print-to-new-tab-in-javascript if it works

Comment: Possible duplicate of [create html page and print to new tab in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27248259/create-html-page-and-print-to-new-tab-in-javascript)

Comment: @vatz88 
pdf document is not displayed

Comment: @Haem 
pdf document is not displayed

Comment: See if you can make a blob url and use it in an iframe.

Comment: @vatz88 I tried but it didn’t work, maybe you can help and give your decision

Answer (score 2):

```
                const binary = atob(pdfSrc.replace(/\s/g, ''));
                const len = binary.length;
                const buffer = new ArrayBuffer(len);
                const view = new Uint8Array(buffer);
                for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    view[i] = binary.charCodeAt(i);
                }
                const blob = new Blob([view], {type: "application/pdf"});
                const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
                iframe.style.display = 'none';
                iframe.src = url;
                document.body.appendChild(iframe);
                iframe.contentWindow.print();
```

Comment: Thanks dude, two and a half hours that i'm looking for something that works :)

Answer (score 0):

We define the function that base64 string convert to ArrayBuffer

```
const base64ToArrayBuffer = (data) => {
    const bString = window.atob(data);
    const bLength = bString.length;
    let bytes = new Uint8Array(bLength);
    for (let i = 0; i < bLength; i++) {
        const ascii = bString.charCodeAt(i);
        bytes[i] = ascii;
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

```
 const content = base64ToArrayBuffer(base64PDF);
 const blob = new Blob([content], { type: "application/pdf" });
 const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

 const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
 iframe.style.display = 'none';
 iframe.src = url;
 document.body.appendChild(iframe);
 iframe.contentWindow.print();
```